# Как удалить определённый символ из строки?

Tags: c++

Пример: есть строка `s1 = "balboon"` и строка `s2 = "bon"`. нужно пройтись циклом и найти все буквы `s2` и удалить их из `s1` и `s2`. Чтобы на выводе у нас получилось: `albo - "пустая строка" == std::cout << str1<< " - "<< str2 << '\n';`

Есть пример кода который я написал и пытался разными способами менять, но без успешно

```
  s1 = "balboon";
  s2 = "bon";
  std::string str1 = s1;
  std::string str2 = s2;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < s2.length() ; i++)
  {
      char two = s2[i];
      size_t found2 = s2.find(two);
    
      for(int j = 0; j < s1.length() ; j++)
      {
          char one = s1[j];
          size_t found1 = s1.find(one);
        
          if(s2[i] == s1[j])
          {
              str1.erase(found1, 1);
              str2.erase(found2, 1);
          }
      }
  }
  
  std::cout << str1<< " - "<< str2 << '\n';
```

Comment: `s1.erase(s1.find(s2),s2.size())`. `find` должен не вернуть `npos`

Answer (score 0):

Тут еcть несколько проблем.

1. У `s1` и `s2` должны быть заданы типы данных (т.е. `string`).
2. В цикле вы ориентируетесь на длину строки `s1` (или `s2`), а удаляете символы из другой (str1 и str2), следствие - выход за пределы массива.
3. Не ясна суть задачи: если удалить все вхождения символов строки 2 в строку 1, то вы получите результат `al` а не `albo`, как в примере. Если только первое вхождение, то условие в цикле вообще неверно.
   Итого: для случая когда нужно удалить все вхождения символов:

   ```
   int main()
    {
        const std::string s1 = "balboon";
        const std::string s2 = "bon";
        std::string str1 = s1;
        std::string str2 = s2;
      while(str2.length() > 0)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < str1.length(); j++)
          {
              if (str2[0] == str1[j])
              { 
                  str1.erase(j, 1); 
                  j--;
              }
          }
          str2.erase(0, 1);
      }
      std::cout <<s1.c_str() <<" - "<< s2.c_str() <<" = "<< str1.c_str() << '\n';
    }
   ```

Для второго случая: замените строку `j--;` на `break;`

Для ситуации, описанной в коментариях:

```
for(int i = 0;i<str2.length();i++)
    {   
        bool isDel = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < str1.length(); j++)
        {
            if (str2[i] == str1[j])
            {
                str1.erase(j, 1);
                j--;
                isDel = true;
            }
        }
        if (isDel)
        {
            str2.erase(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ненадо так `while(str2.length() > 0)`.  А если в str2 есть символ, которого нет в str1 ?

Comment: @Chorkov, Из задания: "нужно пройтись циклом и найти все буквы s2 и удалить их из s1 и s2". Не сказано, что их не нужно удалять из `s2` если символа нет в `s1`. Если все же ваше предположение верно, то это решение в целом неверное, т.к. вложенный цикл предпологает, что из `s2` проверенный символ удаляется. Поэтому добавил вариант и для вашего случая.